# How to inject cordovaHTTP plugin with Angular

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to implement HTTPS(with server certificate, placed in platform->android->asset as defined in cordova-HTTP plugin documention) web service for Hybrid application.I have successfully added the cordova plugin for android platform.I have 
loaded the module in my app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
```

Now i am trying to use it in controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['cordovaHTTP'])
  .controller('loginScreenCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('inside Test App controller');
    $scope.ShowAlert = function() {
      console.log('inside onButtonClick');
      cordovaHTTP.enableSSLPinning(true, function() {
        console.log('success!');
    }, function() {
        console.log('error :(');
});
```

but i have got "Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cordovaHTTP due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." exception

Let me know any suggestion for the same

Comment: you missed to implement following: please replace: **angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])** with **angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'cordovaHTTP' ])**

Comment: @Naitik : I have replaced the line as suggested by you but got below error:

Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cordovaHTTP due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: remove and add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP plugin again. May be your plugin is not installed properly

Comment: I have gotten below plugin list using  "cordova plugin list" command:====

cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-http 1.1.0 "SSL Pinning"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

Comment: please remove cordova-plugin-http 1.1.0 which is version old please update new version 1.2.0 of cordova-plugin-http by following command: 
**cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-http** and **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http**

Comment: I have removed the old version and add the updated version but got same issue

Comment: please post whole app.js code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118210/discussion-between-yogesh-chander-and-naitik).

Comment: @Naitik was this ever resolved?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency

> cordovaHTTP

in **app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'cordovaHTTP'])
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Regards.

Comment: I have added 'cordovaHTTP' as suggested by you but got below error:

Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cordovaHTTP due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: have you included js file for `cordovaHTTP ` in index.html  ?